# How to count null values in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, null

```
select distinct "column" from table;
```

output:

```
    column
1     0.0
2     [null]
3     1.0
```

But when I try to count the null values

```
select count("column") from train where "column" is NULL;
```

Gives output 0 (zero)

Can you suggest where it's going wrong?

Comment: Hint : use `count(*)` instead of `column_name`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `count(*)`:

```
select count(*) from train where "column" is NULL;
```

`count()` with any other argument counts the non-NULL values, so there are none if `"column"` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 20):

Use **SUM**

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column_null_tally
FROM table;
```

Comment: `SUM((column IS NULL)::int) AS column_null_tally` will do the same

Answer (score 8):

Some workaround when you want to count the values on aggregations, including NULL ones, but can't use `count(*)` (if other columns are different too).

On these cases, you can use this request :

```sql
count(distinct("column")) + (CASE bool_or("column" is null) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

The `count(distinct(column))` will count the non null values, and the other part will add `1` if there is a null value

Answer (score 6):

Use [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "column" IS NULL) AS is_null,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "column" < 1.0) AS lt_one,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "column" > 1.0) AS gt_one,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "column" = 1.0) AS just_perfect
FROM "table";
```

Answer (score 0):

You get zero because you are counting null (empty) values, you need to count values from a field that is not empty, like the id field.

```
select count("id_column") from train where "data_column" is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since

- `select count(coalesce(t."column", 0)) from table t` is the full number of rows, with and without NULL:s and
- `select count(t."column") from table t` is the number of rows without NULL:s,

this works as well:

```
Select count(coalesce(t."column", 0)) - count(t."column") FROM table t;
```

*(This answer might also help those who came here to count both NULL and not NULL, at least I was stranded here since I was searching for that)*.